# Making traversal generic in scala

Tags: scala

I know there are already some ways of making traversal generic in scala, but I'm trying to define a simple trait that encapsulates a traversable type. However, I'm having trouble getting the type signatures to work out. A first attempt would be something like the following:

```
trait Traversable1[B] {
  def head: Option[B]
  def next: Traversable1[B]
}
```

This works well, except I want `next` to return an object that has the same type as the original traversable, not the more generic traversable type. For example, if `List` has the trait `Traversable1`, it's `next` method should return something of type `List`, not `Traversable1`. Thus, my second attempt was the following:

```
trait Traversable2[A[B] <: Traversable2[A[B]] {
  def head: Option[B]
  def next: A[B]
}
```

Here, `A` could equal `List`, so `next` would return a `List[B]`. Unfortunately, this code does not compile: `A[B] takes no type parameters, expected: one`

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Isn't this what Iterable is for?

Comment: Yes, probably. I have more complicated examples I'm working with, and trying to more deeply understand Scala's typesystem and syntax so that I can use the right solution in such more complicated novel situations.

Comment: You might find the implementation of `scalaz.Traverse` to be of interest. As noted, it's based on http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a trait like:

```
trait Traversable[T[_]] {
    def head[A](t: T[A]): Option[A]
    def next[A](t: T[A]): T[A]
}
```

then implement it for lists like:

```
implicit val listTraversable = new Traversable[List] {
    def head[A](l: List[A]) = l match {
        case Nil => None
        case x::_ => Some(x)
    }

    def next[A](l: List[A]) = l.tail
}
```

You can then make use of it using the 'type class' pattern by taking an implicit implementation of the trait to do the work e.g.

```
def foreach[T[_], A](t: T[A], f: A => Unit)(implicit trav: Traversable[T]): Unit = {
    trav.head(t) match {
        case Some(v) =>
            f(v)
            foreach(trav.next(t), f)
        case None => ()
    }
}
```

and call it with

```
foreach(List(1,2,3), println)
```

Comment: This looks right, but can you explain how this would be used in practice? If I have a function that accepts a `Traversable` when I have a `List`, do I need to pass both the `List` and the singleton `listTraversable`? Or is there a way to implicitly give a `List` this functionality? I think I don't understand the syntax of such traits that simply define functions that accept the data they are encapsulating.

Comment: @jonderry - Yes you can supply the implementing trait using implicits, see update.